# COBOL PICTURE with V and Comma

Tags: cobol

I am learning some basics with open COBOL, and here is my question about PICTURE:

999V99 VALUE 12.4
displays "012.40"

I would also expect
99,999V99 VALUE 12.4 to produce some reasonable output, but the output is "00,01240" instead.

99,999V99 VALUE 1234.56
also displays "01,23456" and not "01,234.56" as I would expect.

What is wrong? What is the correct mask to obtain "01,234.56" from 1234.56?

Comment: Show your code. Read about the meaning of the symbols in a PICTURE clause. Hint: A "9" represents one position in the number, and leading zeroes are displayes as such. There is another symbol which causes leading zeroes to be supressed.

Comment: Here's IBM's [COBOL Picture Clause](https://www.ibmmainframer.com/cobol-tutorial/cobol-picture-clause/)

Comment: `999V99 VALUE 12.4` displays "012.40": no it doesn't. It displays "01240". You need a dot in the `PICTURE` to get a dot out. V is an implied decimal point, not a physical one. A `PICTURE` string with both `,` and `V` makes no sense. You should use `9,999.99` if you want both commas and a dot.

Comment: sorry, I was writing from a mobile.

Comment: **[No Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)** of code or data. Always provide a [mre] with code, **data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct mask is `99,999.99`. Have a look at the link Gilbert suggested in the comments

```
Common mask characters 

    9 - 0 -> 9
    Z - 0 -> 9 + space for leading zero's
    V - Assumed decimal place not actually represented
    . - actual decimal place
    , - comma 

So
    Cobol definition           Display value
    ----------------           -------------
    99,999V99 VALUE 1234.56    01,23456 
    99,999.99 VALUE 1234.56    01,234.56 
    ZZ,ZZ9.99 VALUE 1234.56     1,234.56
    --,--9.99 VALUE 1234.56     1,234.56
    --,--9.99 VALUE -1234.56   -1,234.56
    ++,++9.99 VALUE 1234.56    +1,234.56
```

Once you use characters like `Z , . - + /` the field is and **edited numeric** field rather than a *numeric* field. Some compilers may let you use *edited numeric* in numeric calculations other will not. *edited numeric* are for displaying values.

#### Numeric fields

Numeric fields are defined like the following and can be used in numeric calculations

```
      03 num-1         pic s9(5)v99.
      03 num-2         pic s9(5)v99 comp.
      03 num-3         pic s9(5)v99 comp-3.
```